# Halacha and Stockmarket

Tags: halacha, money

Are there certain Stocks or ETFs that a  Jew is not allowed to invest in ?

Reasons could be chillul Shabbat, unethical behaviour,
not kosher food etc. commited by the companies buisness dealings.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't mean to close in one go, but see if that other questions helps. Feels they are real duplicates. Let us know otherwise